# How to store encrypted-dp{encrypted-password} using Windows odbcconf CONFIGSYSDSN or Set-OdbcDsn in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encryption, passwords, odbc, datasource

When I edit a password in ODBC Data Source through a Windows "ODBC Data Source Administrator" dialog window, the password is stored in an encrypted manner like `encrypted-dp{encrypted-password}` in Windows registry.

When I edit the password using `odbcconf CONFIGSYSDSN`, it is stored as plain text in the registry.

Is there a way to store a data source password using programmatic way/script in the same way as the Windows ODBC dialog window does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it was an external library, which was editing data source properties, encryption wasn't made as a part of the Windows process.

This lib was encrypting the password when changing the properties over the Data Source edit window - which was already a proprietary 3rd party window, coming from the lib.

We got an exposed "encrypt" method from the vendor, so we can also encrypt the password ourselves when using PowerShell.